Laravel - Dusk How to run a dusk command with code on a production environment?
In a function of class i have this code
public function ....
...
$command = 'php artisan dusk --filter=FetchSingleProductDetailTest';
$output = shell_exec($command);
...

It worked in local environment but not on a production environment, running the manual command php artisan dusk --filter=FetchSingleProductDetailTest on production environment ran successfully, no errors but could not run with the code
i try to follow with this post but it's return the error The "pest" option does not exist., even though i installed pestphp/pest-plugin-laravel, pestphp/pest and ran the command php artisan pest:install.
Any solutions to fix this problem?

@DishanSachin you mean pest must be under require?

I looked into it and found that other people have been facing the same issue. I couldn't find a fix that works, but these discussions might give you some helpful information.

https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/371
https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/1039

